# Possible mistake in Apostol's book: "An introduction to analytical number theory" (?)

Tags: group-theory, number-theory, proof-verification

On page 132 of Apostol's "An introduction to analytical number theory" :

**Theorem 6.6:** Let $G'$ be a subgroup of a finite abelian group $G$, where $G' \neq G$.
Choose an element $a \in G$, $a \notin G'$, and let $h$ be the indicator of $a$ in $G'$.

Then the set of products $G''=\{xa^k:x \in G' \text{ and } k=0,1,2, \dots ,h- 1 \}$  is a subgroup of $G$ which contains $G'$.

Moreover, the order of $G$  is $h$ times
that of $G'$, $|G''| = h * |G'|$ .

**My problem:** 
I think the statement $a \notin G'$ is too weak as $G' \subset  <a> $ with $a \notin G'$ still holding, but giving: $|G''| \neq h * |G'|$ .

**For example:** One may consider  $ G \supsetneq <2> = \{0,2,4,6,8,10\}$ and choose $G' = <4> = \{0,4,8 \} $ with $0$ being neutral element, $ a = 2$, and addition the operation of choice in $G$.

I find: $<4> \subset <2> $ and thus: $|G''| = |<2>| \neq 6 *|<4>| = 6*3 = 18$ with $6$ being the the indicator $h$ of $<2>$

Therefore one could either generalize the Theorem **$6.6.$** or further postulate that $<a> \bigcap G' = \{e\}$

Are my thoughts on the Theorem correct? Any constructive comment/answer is appreciate. As always thanks in advance.

Comment: I"m not familiar with the terminology "indicator" in this context, but if (and only if) $h$ is the smallest positive integer with $a^h\in G'$, then the claim about $|G''|$ seems to be correct.

Comment: In the statement of the Theorem, $h$ is the indicator of $a$, not the indicator of $<a>$. That makes sense, because the indicator of $2$ in $G'$ is $2$, not $6$.

Comment: @TonyK, yes, my problem is resolved, in fact my problem was exactly as you have stated it :) . Case closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue seems to be what the "indicator of $a$ in $G'$" might mean. I'm not familiar with that terminology, but one sensible thing for it to mean is the smallest integer $h > 0$ such that $a^h \in G'$. This works in your example, because $|G''|=6$ and $h \times |G'| = 2 \times 3 = 6$.

Comment: $h$ is supposed to be the smallest integer for which $a^h = 0$.  I found it weird, that Apostol stated $a \notin G' $ and said $h$ would be the indicator of $a$ in $G'$ . 
However now I find the theorem very clear and furthermost correct, as it is stated, thus my mistake. I have to thank you and Andreas Blass!